# Java HttpURLConnection java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

The second line throws `java.net.UnknownHostException`.
I was in a internal network in my company, and I hope I can help another one who's also in the same internal network with me to visit the website, and I just want to read content from the URL and give the content to the client side, is there any one help me on this?

Comment: Can you show us the value of `urlStr` ??

Comment: You can find more details from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception

Comment: This is a DNS problem, not a programming problem. If your local DNS doesn't recognize the hostname you're using, this is what happens.

Comment: you can use `nslookup` to validate your url.

Comment: Hi, "String urlStr = request.getParameter("url");" this just comes from the form submition which is the url I want to visit.

Comment: Hi EJP, if this is a DNS problem, why can't visit ant site expect my localhost, and I'm unable to change the DNS settings in my computer.

Comment: Hi Sarkar, I got "Can't find address for server xxx.com: Non-existent domain" when using nslookup command.

Answer (score 0):

Companys normally have a proxy server to the outside world. Try to configure the proxy data in a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html) class and open the connection with proxy.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(<ProxyUrl>,<ProxyPort>));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

If your proxy has a passwort authentication you have to set the log in data in an Authenticator:

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() 
{

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
    {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(<ProxyUser>,<ProxyPW>.toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Comment: Hi Thorgas, Is the <ProxyUrl> and <ProxyPort> comes from the url which I'm going to visit?

Comment: No, it's the Url & Port from the companys proxy server, which routes all the internet traffic from the internal company net to the outside net. Try to find the proxy configuration in your Browser(Firefox: Options -> Advanced -> Tab Network->Settings). But firefox is able to auto detect the proxy connection. You can also look and try this: http://superuser.com/questions/337685/how-do-i-change-the-windows7-lan-proxy-config-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the proxy settings, here is the result of executing command "netsh winhttp show proxy" : Current WinHTTP proxy settings:   Direct access (no proxy server).