# the httpclient4.3.5 run android emulator throw the 'java.net.UnknownHostException'

Tags: android, emulation

No address associated with hostname

but it work well in real device!
can you meet the scene

Answer (score 1):

Give internet permission in manifest file,

**<
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>**

**<
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>**

And also change your url into IP like,

**www.google.com** into **74.125.29.138**

If you don`t know IP address use this link-http://freelabs.info/UrlToIpOnline.aspx

Comment: i gived all the internet permission~, it run well  in my phone

Comment: Change your url into IP.. Like 128.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Possible Dupicate of 
[UnkownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484290/1292177)

It also occur when you don't have the internet permission or internet/wifi not enabled.

Comment: it can get the response from localhost of my pc,it may be something wrong in DNS

Comment: do you have working internet on device and internet permission too ?