# how to connect intuit quickbooks using java program (Restful ws)?

Tags: java, quickbooks-online

I write a java code to access(connect) intuit quickbooks using this keys

```
String consumerKey = "qyprdTCZTGRhIYkRPU5OeXjd7rJiMS";

String consumerSecret = "L1ek9k7zX55rVXPlj5FikHYJgCnxfWCKBtjt81Ti";

String accessToken="qyprd6GGQ9w3OfmN0tg1M5xLzWdWF9RZOaMRVkb43tXNO6kG";

String accessTokenSecret = "RMKyYmrrqQY0xem2Cxj3pQeiOJwSR3ceT90wESWH";
String companyId = "1386063640";

String appId="b7qs4z3s2p";
```

when i execute this i got these errors

```
connection refused
or
java.net.UnknownHostException: sandboxquickbooks.api.intuit.com
```

please any one help to getting out this isue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the computer does not recognize the server you re attempting to connect to. The address sandboxquickbooks.api.intuit.com is not able to be located by your computer when executing the code. Take a look at this post for a little more detail...

[java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid hostname for server: local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception)

My guess is it is spelled wrong, or they changed the address/url.

Answer (score 0):

Correct sandbox base url is - https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Refer java sample app here-
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java