# IBM Worklight Android Build and Deploy errors

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building an Android application using IBM Worklight. I keep getting the follow errors:

> android build failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: nodename nor
>   servname provided, or not known
>   Application 'WellPointMobile' with
>   environment 'android' build finished with errors.

How can I stop these errors from appearing in Eclipse?

Comment: I've seen that error quite a lot when switching networks (e.g. between WiFi networks). Try restarting Eclipse and/or your system.

Answer (score -1):

This is not related to Worklight, but to OS X and Java.
Have you searched the error in Google?

See here: http://biomedicalontologies.com/2012/11/14/fixing-java-net-local-host-name-unknown-error-on-mac-os-x/

You can also edit your hosts file:
Open Terminal and:

1. Type `hostname`; copy the value.
2. Type `sudo vi /etc/hosts`; type your password

   My hosts file looks like this:

   > 127.0.0.1 mbp-idan localhost
   >   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost ::1 localhost

   You should see something similar. Simply add your hostname after "127.0.0.1".
3. Log out of the user account and log back in. The error should no longer happen in Eclipse.

Comment: "android build failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: nodename nor servname provided, or not known". Actually, this seems to be a fairly common error in Eclipse/MFP.

Comment: It's not failing because of MFP... I've seen it in the past and the error is very common. MFP is just another victim of it. The fix will help also MFP.

Comment: Edit the hosts file, restart Eclipse (actually maybe sign out and back in from the user account) and it'll go away.

Comment: +1, check it out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception