# Cannot connecto to external database from inside kubernetes pod

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to connect my spring-boot api inside a kubernetes pod to an external database (a separate machine but within the local network), however when running, I get SQLNonTransientConnectionException, UknownHostException: mysql-svc, the api cannot connect to the database but whenever I ping the database address from inside the pod using kubectl exec -it, I can ping it successfully, anybody who has experienced the same error as mine?

here is my application.properties connection uri and kubernetes objects:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-svc/test?autoReconnect=true

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mysql-svc
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 3306
   targetPort: 3306
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
 name: mysql-svc
subsets:
 - addresses:
   - ip: 10.0.123.28
   ports:
   - port: 3306
     name: mysql-svc
```

Answer (score 2):

After hours of digging and reconfiguring, I finally get it to work, thanks to Xenwar from kubernetes group for pointing out the externalIP property, it turns out that i need to point my app to an external ip, in this case the database, here is the service object:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-con
spec:
  selector:
    app: api2
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  externalIPs:
    - 10.0.123.28
```

Comment: Did you change your EndPoints object? I kind of confuse since the services are different. Can you show me your full code?

Comment: It worked for me as well, but I was not able to do it using endpoints. Confused.

Comment: can you please share your deployment yml?

Answer (score 0):

You service is not a "headless" service. Set the IP to None:

```
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
   - port: 3306
     targetPort: 3306
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

Comment: im getting invalid value value: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "None": field is immutable

Comment: Maybe it is not letting you change the IP once it is created. Try removing the service and re-creating it.

Comment: I already did, i removed the type entry as well but to no avail, I still can't access the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need a ExternalName [service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

> [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname): Maps the Service to the contents of the
>   externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a CNAME
>   record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up.

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

> When looking up the host `my-service.prod.svc.cluster.local`, the
>   cluster DNS Service returns a CNAME record with the value
>   `my.database.example.com`. Accessing my-service works in the same way as
>   other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection
>   happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: still getting this error: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-svc, I was wondering if the problem is in my application.properties file..

Comment: In that case please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/java-net-unknownhostexception-invalid-hostname-for-server-local)